# Custom Web Service Using Servlet

Tags: web-services, servlets

I would like to implement a servlet representing a web service endpoint. That servlet should intercept the XML sent to it and read its content among other information it receives. I know that is possible since Spring-WS takes a similar approach. Can you suggest how I can implement a servlet like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **naive** way that is on top of my head to achieve what you need, hopefully it will get you started.

### Scenario

You have a library app. Suppose you want to have an API endpoint a client can use to create a book that is described by an xml file. The xml file will be sent to a Servlet.
The example endpoint API url is:
**http://localhost:8080/api/books**

### Step 1

Create a Servlet called CreateBookServlet

```
// servlet mapping
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreateBookServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/books</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Step 2

```
// ...
public class CreateBookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String xmlStr = request.getParameter("xmlbook");

        // better use some xml library to parse xml to Book object
        Book book = xmlLibrary.parse(xmlStr);
        //save the Book object to database
        bookService.create(book);
    }

    // since it's a creation of an entity, we use POST instead of GET method
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

### Step 3

Send a post request to CreateBookServlet (http://localhost:8080/api/books) with a parameter whose name is "xmlbook" and value is a simple string containing the xml code of the new book to create. The xml string can be created by reading an xml file, of course.

### Summary

A lot of important things are omitted here such as security, xml parsing and so on, but this simple approach will do what you ask, I hope.

Comment: Can I use a Web Service client to access this service?

Comment: @SandahAung In general, Any program that can send a HTTP request(using POST method in this case) will be able to use this service. e.g., regular java application(android, web app, etc.), a javascript +HTML only web application and even another web service will be able to do so if you wish. Sometimes an XML file has a node that contains another resource(e.g. author's profile's url) that your webservice will use to meet the business requirment. So yes, short answer is you can.